# String[] cannot be converted to State[]

Tags: java

Just wondering what I have done wrong here I'm getting an error in the method `setLine()` which is:

> error:   incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to State[]

Im not too sure on what to do to fix it since I need the line to be split and stored in that state array so I can determine whether if it is a state or location when reading from a `csv` file.

```
public static void readFile(String inFilename)
{
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    int stateCount = 0, locationCount = 0;
    String line;

    try
    {
        fileStrm = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        line = bufRdr.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            if (line.startsWith("STATE"))
            {
                stateCount++;
            }
            else if (line.startsWith("LOCATION"))
            {
                locationCount++;
            }
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
        }
        fileStrm.close();

        State[] state = new State[stateCount];
        Location[] location = new Location[locationCount];
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (fileStrm != null)
        {
            try { fileStrm.close(); } catch (IOException ex2) { }
        }
        System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void processLine(String csvRow)
    {
        String thisToken = null;
        StringTokenizer strTok;
        strTok = new StringTokenizer(csvRow, ":");
        while (strTok.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            thisToken = strTok.nextToken();
            System.out.print(thisToken + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

public static void setLine(State[] state, Location[] location, int stateCount, int locationCount, String line)
{
    int i;
    state = new State[stateCount];
    state = line.split("="); <--- ERROR
    for( i = 0; i < stateCount; i++)
    {
    }
}

public static void writeOneRow(String inFilename)
{
    FileOutputStream fileStrm = null;
    PrintWriter pw;
    try
    {
        fileStrm = new FileOutputStream(inFilename);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fileStrm);
        pw.println();
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (fileStrm != null)
        {
            try
            {
                fileStrm.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex2)
            {}
        }
        System.out.println("Error in writing to file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: `state = line.split("=")` you get the error because `state` is of type `State[]`, whereas `line.split("=")` returns a `String[]`. You cannot assign freely between arbitrary types. You have to iterate the resulting String array and use the elements to parse `State` objects yourself.

Comment: could you provide the code for the class `State`.

Comment: @Karan why ? You think `State` would inherite `String` ? `String` is `final` so unlikely.

Comment: @AxelH it does make sense. Maybe the class has already a constructor that takes a String?

Comment: @QBrute I get you, but explaining the problem would be enough for OP to adapt. This is a basic problem, meaning that he need to understand it, not just paste a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs, as it just says *'`String[]` cannot be converted to `State[]`'*. That is like you wanted to store an `Integer` into a `String`, it's the same, because the types don't have a relation to each other (parent -> child).

So if you want to solve your problem you need a method which converts the `String[]` into a `State[]`. Something like this:

```
private State[] toStateArray(String[] strings){
    final State[] states = new State[strings.length];
    for(int i = strings.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        states[i] = new State(strings[i]); // here you have to decide how to convert String to State
    }
    return states;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help. I tried to add that into my code and now i get the error line in the for loop: **constructor State in class State cannot be applied to given types;**

for the line of code: `states[i] = new State(strings[i]);`

Comment: Yeah, that's because this constructor (`State(String)`) doesn't exists. It's now on you to decide what constructor needs to be used, but my example should give you the idea how ;)